# Error loading GeoTIFF using raster2pgsql: “Error 1: PROJ: Cannot find proj.db”

Tags: postgis, postgresql, arcgis-server, raster2pgsql

I am attempting to load a GeoTiff into a PostgreSQL database using the PostGIS extension `raster2pgsql`. When running the executable, I receive the following error: `Error 1: PROJ: Cannot find proj.db`. The only file with that name resides in the path `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.0\proj`. I've added that path to my `Path` variable in my environment settings, but running `raster2pgsql` still returns the same error. I then get a message saying the program `raster2pgsql` has stopped working.

This is the command I'm running in Command Prompt. I've put placeholder user/database names in quotes. If any syntax is incorrect or doesn't make sense please inform me:

```
raster2pgsql -I -C C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\arcgis-data\ "tifname".tif | psql -h "hostname" -p 5432 -d "database name" -U "username"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to specify the path to `proj.db` in an `PROJ_LIB` environment variable.

See [proj documentation](https://proj.org/usage/environmentvars.html#envvar-PROJ_LIB)

Comment: Thank you, that worked!